# What is Datomic Ions?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I couldn't understand when I should consider to use [Datomic Ions](https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/ions/ions.html).

What are the benefits besides having plain Clojure + Datomic project setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefits are listed at https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/ions/ions.html#benefits. Develop your functions at the REPL, deliver them on AWS a minute later.

For an extended walkthrough, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BRO-Xb32Ic.